# Insert numbers from VBA to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm writing in VBA some numbers:

[image]

I want that it insert in Excel cell:

[image]

This is my code but it is not working correctly, takes much more time.

```
Private Sub Num_Article_Info_Generale_Change()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Activate

    Range("A$2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text
End Sub
```

Any solution or different way?

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening when you run the code? And where is your Num_Article_Info_Generale object?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? What is not working?, PS: I would say if the above need before end sub `application.screenupdating = true`. Additionally I would change `"ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Activate
Range("A$2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text"` to `sheets("Données Enregistrées").range("A2").value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text`

Comment: @Philippe you don't need the `Application.ScreenUpdating = true` at the end because when the Sub reaches `End Sub` it will automatically flip it back to `true`

Comment: It's probably slow because it is activating the worksheet and updating the cell every time there's any **change** in the textbox.  This means that every time you type a character, the code runs.  Every time you delete a character, the code runs.  I would recommend having this code be on a different event (or a button), removing the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` line, and instead of activating the sheet, just use: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données Enregistrées").Range("A2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text`

Comment: @MichalKrzych : okay, well i have always used it. and it didn't got worst by doing it :), thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Comment: I thank you for your answer...very friendly to help me. Now It's working, Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données Enregistrées").Range("A2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text
```

Instead of :

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Données Enregistrées").Activate

Range("A$2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text
```

Use a button at the end of your application instead of tracking "change" on TextBox

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Données Enregistrées").Range("A2").Value = Num_Article_Info_Generale.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear,I still cannot because my reputation is too low ((